# nodejs: confused about 404 middleware

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript, http-status-code-404

So I implemented a 404 middleware for my app. I initially had it as a last route, but then followed recommendations (notably Express' [FAQ](http://expressjs.com/starter/faq.html)), and used a middleware function.

But now I am puzzled. I put a debug message in my middleware function, and it seems EVERY request is actually executing that middleware (as I can see the debug message on every request in the output, even successful requests)! This annoys me, what am I doing wrong?

Here's my app code (watch out: coffeescript). I am posting the whole file because sometimes middleware, routes etc may interfere with each other, and the examples I found just show the 404 middleware itself. Nevertheless omitted some code for brevity's sake:

```
#Omitted all requires for brevity

#########################################################
# Connect to DB 
#########################################################
loc = process.env.LOCATION || 'local'
db = mongoose.connect(config.db.mongoose_auth_local)

#########################################################
# Initiallize the application
#########################################################
app = module.exports = express()

env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
if ('development' == env)
  app.use(errorhandler())

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('view engine','jade')
#########################################################
# Initiallize the middleware 
#########################################################
app.use session(
  secret: 'myapp',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false 
  )

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'))
app.use(flash())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

#########################################################
# Middleware authentication functions 
#########################################################
# Check user is admin
is_admin = (req, res, next) ->
  #check if user is admin, omitted


LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy( (username, password, done) ->
  #passport setup, omitted
)

passport.serializeUser( (user, done) ->
  done(null, user._id)
)

passport.deserializeUser((id,done) ->
  User.findById(id, (err, user) ->
    done(err, user)
  )
)

#########################################################
# Define user routes 
#########################################################
app.get('/', routes.index)
#some more routes, omitted

app.post '/login', (req, res, next) ->
  #login function, omitted

#>>>>>>>>>>>THE 404 MIDDLEWARE function with the debug output <<<<<<<<<<
app.use((req, res, next) ->
  debug("404 middleware")
  err = new Error('Not Found')
  res.status = 404
  res.render('404')
)

app.use( (error, req, res, next) ->
  res.status(500)
  res.render('500')


port = process.env.PORT || config.app.port
info("Configured port for the application is : " + port)

app.listen(port, () ->
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", port, app.settings.env)
  )
```

Comment: So where is your 404 middleware? If you placed it where there's the comment "initialize the middleware", you should move it to the bottom.

Comment: @Zlatko If you go further down, you'll find "Define user routes" and below that I have a commented line "#>>>>>The 404 MIDDLEWARE function with the debug output <<<<<<<", there it is, practically at the end

Comment: Oh, didn't scroll, small screen and it didn't see.

Comment: I assume you're not calling that `next()` in the prior routes, right? I don't see anything wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but there was no real "problem", it was a misunderstanding from my side....

In fact the middleware was all configured and working right.

The issue is that I had a "/images/logo.png" in my view, but there was no logo.png in my static folder...thus node was correctly entering the 404 middleware function :)

Sorry for cluttering the space with such a question.